# Android studio, Kotlin plugin error "Unsupported format, plugin version: 202-1.5.31..."

Tags: android

suddenly this error pop-up in android studio (4.2.1). Unsupported format, plugin version: 202-1.5.31....

What I tried to do:

1. Menu Build - Clean project
2. Menu Build - Rebuild project
3. Tools >> #Kotlin# >> configure #Kotlin# Plugin updates.
   I have the latest versions of 1.5 and 1.6.
4. I deleted the old (version 1.5) of Katlin plugin from Android Studio. Restarted Android Studio and then I tried to install new plugin.
   That did not help.
5. Checked for updates of Android Studio - I have the latest version.

Help me)
thanks in advance